# using "grep", to match a list of IDs in a file to match with another file

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep

I have been using various formats suggested here on the forum like this one:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt > ouput.txt
```

`file1.txt` contains a list of IDs in one column e.g.:

```
15002345234 
15001234214
```

`file2.txt` contains tab delimited columns, one column including the IDs, and other columns containing other information.

```
1500349850 1 3 father
```

I have tried shell loops, `awk` and `sed` commands suggested in other posts. But essentially I only get results for one ID:

```
150982309750 1 2 2  4
```

it is always the same one as well, whereas there should be many results in the output e.g.:

```
150982309750 1 2 2  4
150563524856 1 3 2  2
150864364612 2 1 2  2
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: so sorry if this was not clear. I will try and edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

- add the `-w` option to only match whole words
- add the `-F` option for fixed-string (not regular expression) matching
- verify that file1 does not use `\r\n` line endings -- the trailing `\r` would throw off the matching. Check this with `head file1.txt | od -c`

```bsh
grep -wFf <(sed 's/\r$//' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Comment: Many many thanks this worked! Would you be able to point me to where i can read up on this specific argument that you used: <(sed 's/\r$//'

Comment: That is a [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) -- essentially it's a way for bash to run some code in a subshell and be able to read the results like a file.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. Can't thank you enough for solving this for me.